# Internet Explorer Presentation

Tags: css, internet-explorer, presentation

on the page [reindl-haustechnik.de](http://reindl-haustechnik.de) I have a problem with the presentation in the internet explorer.

I use IE 9.

The image of the slider is not correctly....

On chrome and Firefox is all right

Thanks 4 help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `<!DOCTYPE`, just like you're supposed to. Otherwise browsers fall back to Quirks Mode. In Firefox and Chrome, Quirks Mode is almost identical to Standards Mode, but IE's been around significantly longer and therefore its Quirks Mode is how it looked  in IE 5.5.